# Java opens file successfully when run in Eclipse but not in Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, file-io

I have been working on a project in Eclipse that requires me to open a file.  It's working as expected.  I imported my project into Netbeans just to check it out but when run, the file can't be opened.  I think a screenshot would be most helpful in this case:

[image: screenshot of the problem in Netbeans]

Any idea what the issue is?  I've even explicitly specified the run directory in the project properties and that still doesn't work.

*Additional Info:*

- I just remembered that I'm using the JDK 1.6 in Eclipse but Netbeans is using the JDK 1.7 -- is file path resolution handled differently between the two platforms?

Also, as suggested by a few users, I added in my catch block:

```
System.err.println(new File(inFileName).getAbsolutePath();
```

Which, as it should, returns:

`C:\Users\David\Dev\projects\Autocuration\pearltrees_export_02-07-2012.rdf`

Comment: Where's your declaration of `inFileName`?

Comment: @Mob the constructor for `File` should automatically resolve relative paths against the String returned from `System.getProperty("user.dir");`.  As you can see, both match.  The absolute ur<b>i</b> after the call to the constructor becomes: *C:\Users\David\Dev\projects\Autocuration\pearltrees_export_02-07-2012.rdf*.  I have verified this as per my response to Benoit's answer.

Comment: @Mob the declaration of `inFileName` is `String inFileName = null;`.  Later, if a command line arg is specified, `inFileName` gets assigned that value and the program trys to open the file as an input stream rather than using `System.in`.

Comment: The words `should` and `automatically` are suspicious in my opinion.  The Exception message indicates the path has incorrect syntax.  Maybe there's an extra slash/backslash getting added (or not added) somewhere.  I'd add debug statements in the try block to print the entire path.

Comment: @jahroy see my response to Benoit's answer.  I did as suggested and the resulting path is correct.

Comment: Peculiar. Have you tried restarting netbeans?

Comment: @Mob that's not the problem -- yes Netbeans has been restarted.  I tried running my project in Netbeans a few days ago and I've been sitting on it thinking a *hopefully obvious* solution might come to me.  So I don't think it's any system state dependent factors..

Comment: I see that.  Maybe it would work without the `C:\ `. I would still add a debug statement in the try block to confirm that the `String` is correct (rather than just dumping `File.getAbsolutePath()`).  I would print out `inFileName`. You have a puzzling situation... You may as well debug/print as much info as possible and assume nothing.  Maybe the user is inputting a `\ ` that isn't getting escaped properly... Sorry, just trying to help.

Comment: @jahroy Sure, I'll try that.  And, being the user, I can guarantee that the file is being input simply as: `pearltrees_export_02-07-2012.rdf`

Comment: @jahroy But printing out the *absolute* path of the `File` object created by `new File(inFileName)` yields the exact absolute path I would enter if I did so through the command line.  I think you have a valid point, so I'll give it a shot, but it shouldn't return anything different..

Comment: @jahroy Yes, I understand your point.  In this case, I'm more interested as to *why* it's not working, not necessarily finding a workaround solution.

Comment: @jahroy I tried using an absolute path and I get the same error, only now the absolute path of the file is in the error message, and not the relative path.

Comment: Pretty baffling... Have you printed the `String` value in the try block?  And the value of `user.dir`?  What about the full path without the `C:\ `?

Comment: @jahroy I found the problem and it indeed seems to be a Netbeans bug.  I'll write up and answer, don't worry (=

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After attempting to construct the URI manually,

```
System.out.println(new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")).toURI().resolve(inFileName));
```

I got the following exception:

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in path at index 32: pearltrees_export_02-07-2012.rdf`

Considering there is no 32nd character, I assume the printStackTrace method must trim the string obtained from the exception message before printing.

Whatever the case, it appears that Netbeans parses Run arguments using the ' ' (space) character as a separator.  However, it also includes that space when it passes the arguments to the main method.  In other words, I was trying to open:

`"pearltrees_export_02-07-2012.rdf "`

rather than:

`"pearltrees_export_02-07-2012.rdf"`

Simply trimming argument fixes the problem:

```
inStream = new FileInputStream(new File(inFileName.trim()));
```

Anyway, I cannot find any documentation stating this is the intended behavior as it is certainly different from how the `java` binary behaves (and any other editors I know of).  For this reason I consider this a bug, and I submitted a bug report:

http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=215429

I guess we'll see what the Netbeans fellows have to say..

Comment: I guess there are two lessons here:  1.) Always wrap variables in quotes, brackets, etc... when debugging.  2.) Always use software/IDEs that are bug free!  Glad you solved your issue :)

Comment: @jahroy kinda -- except I wasn't using quotes anywhere.  I'm not sure what #1 is supposed to mean..

Comment: It means when you print a variable for debugging purposes, it helps to wrap the value in quotes or brackets (so you can see whitespace).  Example:  `System.out.println("[" + someString + "]");`  That would have helped you notice the space at the end of your path...

Answer (score 0):

Is the same OS? Same file name? Acording to the message given, it looks like there's some problem in the file name.

Comment: @Rockskull But if you'll notice, I've provided the name of the file that my program is trying to open, working directory that relative path names should be resolved against, and proof that the file in question exists in that location on the file system..

Comment: Have you tried to copy your code to a simpler code to only do that, open the file and print "OK, I opned it" ?

Answer (score 0):

In the catch block you should add this:

```
System.err.println(new File(inFileName).getAbsolutePath());
```

Comment: It's as expected:
C:\Users\David\Dev\projects\Autocuration\pearltrees_export_02-07-2012.rdf